# Manager's trust - does not trust me any meaningful management duties

Tags: management, company-culture, culture

I am a Director of Technology reporting to VP of Technology. I have noticed that my boss started:

1) Personally reviewing all job interviews in my department
2) Wants to pre-screen every single candidate (even if he is on vacation) who wants to apply in my department
3) Does not invite me (or, I should say makes no effort) to engage me to be "Acting" VP while he is gone on vacation or on business trip.
4) Does not ask my opinion  - "how would you do?"

Sounds like the "classic set of signs" for the employee who is marked for extermination , but.... he is OK with me doing other, mostly technical stuff.
Does he needs to learn how to "manage a manager" or I am on my way out?

Comment: We can't know. What have you done to change things?

Comment: If a VP has to resort to micromanaging, there's something seriously wrong. Is there any reason for him to not have enough confidence in your managing skills? Maybe you come across as a "purely technical guy" (or at least he has that impression).

Comment: @Happy: Wish I could upvote your comment ten times. Spot on.

Comment: What makes you think that we know specifically in your VP's mind? We wouldn't know if the VP doesn't have enough to do, you're better placed to know it than we are. Does he need to learn how to manage a manager? If he just started to micro-manage, why wasn't he micro-managing before?  Are you on your way out? You're the one who is best placed to determine whether he has taken over your duties. You are asking the kind of questions that you are best placed to answer.

Comment: How big a department? If there's just you, him, and a couple of juniors, then this kind of thing isn't surprising. How long have you been in role? How long has he been in role? Has he ever appointed you as "Acting" VP?

Answer (score 3):

Really about the only thing to do here is to meet with him and ask him. This should be fairly easy to do if you have regular one-on-one's with him.

Be polite, and don't accuse him or assume ulterior motives. What you should do is put it back on you - say something like "hey, it seems like you're putting a bit more oversight into the management of my team. Is there anything I've done wrong or you'd like me to improve on?"

Answer (score 2):

If these things have started recently, then you have likely lost his trust. That can almost never be restored.

Time to start looking for a new gig.